# blank page with <Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, hyperlink, router

I get a blank page when I use Link.
I should see Events, date, accueil
I use the last version of react-router.
I don't know if I have to delete to?

This is my code:

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// import Header from './components/Header';
import Events from './components/Events/Events';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';



function App() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Marine Mammals</h1>

    <nav>
      <ul>

        <li><Link to="/events">Events</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/date">Date</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/accueil">Accueil</Link></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/Events' element={<Events/>}/>       
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>

    </div>
  );
}



export default App;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Uncaught Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component,                                                                                                              The above error occurred in the <Link> component:at LinkWithRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35499:5), at li,at ul,at nav,at div,at App,Uncaught Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that it is causing an error because Link must be a descendant of the Router (BrowserRouter) component.

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Events from './components/Events/Events';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Marine Mammals</h1>
      <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/events">Events</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/date">Date</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/accueil">Accueil</Link></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/Events' element={<Events/>}/>       
      </Routes>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you. I don't understand when you say he must be a descendant of the router